# How do I style each item in a array when using .map

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am using .map to go through data inside of an array. And I want to style each "bundle of data" seperately. I have multiple sections (Appetizers, Lunch, etc) each section has its own items. How can I seperate each menu item into its own box.

```
import data from "../data";
```

import "./Food.css"

const Food = () => {

```
return (
    <div> <h2 class ="AppHead">Appetizers</h2>
    
    <div class = 'box'>
        {data.appetizers.map((food) => {
                return (

                    <div>                        
                    <div class ="">{food.name}</div>
                    {food.price}
                    {food.description}
                    {Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}
                    </div>
                )
        })}
    </div> </div>
);
    };
```

export default Food;

[This is what I want to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3oO7.png)
[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFyna.png)

I want to recreate that image with CSS.

Comment: Please post your code within your question.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I didn't get what you want exactly. You can assign different `class`es for each bundle of data. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div className='item'>                        
                <div className ="">{food.name}</div>
                {food.price}
                {food.description}
                {Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}
</div>
```

then do whatever styling you want in your css file and it should apply to each rendered menu Item. I think that is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a simple example of how you can accomplish this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eaqzcd?file=src%2FApp.js). You can have your parent data that will look something like this:

```
const data = {
  appetizers: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Fries',
      price: 2.99,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Mozzarella Sticks',
      price: 4.99,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Chicken Wings',
      price: 6.99,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Nachos',
      price: 5.99,
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: 'Spinach Artichoke Dip',
      price: 7.99,
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: 'Bruschetta',
      price: 3.99,
    },
  ],
  drinks: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Coke',
      price: 1.99,
    },
    // Add more drinks here
  ],
  // Add more subgroups here
};
```

Ideally I would recommend making each section their own component. So you could have an Appetizers component where you would pass data.appetizers as a prop where you can then display the data with whatever styling you want. Then do the same for Lunch, Dinner, etc.

That would look something like:

```
    <Appetizers apps={data.appetizers} />
    <Lunch lunch={data.lunch} />
    <Drinks drinks={data.drinks} />
```

Comment: So if you want to "Style" each one separately, then this method would work perfectly. Each component (Apps, Lunch, Dinner, Drinks, etc.) can each have their own stylesheet and format. Inside the "Lunch" component you can access the data through props.lunch. Then do a similar map to what I showed in my example.

Comment: Yeah I plan on making a separate component for each (Appetizer, Dishes , Desserts and Drinks) But I dont know how to style each component in a way where each individual menu item is in its own box/border. As shown in the picture.

Comment: Can u show me an example of how to code what I specified?

Comment: Can you explain what you need in a different way then? What do you mean by you don't know how to style each one. You can create a specific stylesheet for each component. Look into css modules. You can give them each their own styles so the apps looks different from the lunch etc.

Comment: Do like this: `{data.appetizers.map((food) => { return ( <div class='food-item'>`.  And then in css: `.food-item { border: 1px solid #000000; }`.